# Expression Blend doesn't find namespace/class to create sample data

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend, sample

I have a WP7 app that calls a WP7 client library. I added a new class to the client library then I go over to Blend to create sample data for the class. The dialog box to select the class to generate the sample data doesn't show the class or its namespace. Why not?

The class doesn't have an interface or generics and it is public.

I closed/reopened blend. Built the project in VS. What else should I check?

The client library has other namespaces and classes that Blend sample data generation dialog box does find.

Comment: In order to fix this, in Expression Blend I added a new class to the directory. I took the default "Class1.cs". My idea was if I created the class in Blend, it would be able to find the class in order to generate sample data. However, once I added the class, and went over to generate the sample, the entire namespace including the classes I couldn't see before, were now visible. These seems more like a hack but at least I got what I initially wanted.

Comment: It's probably a bug - I have only ever seen this happen when I forgot to recompile my project after adding the new class.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your project is compiled after adding the class files. In Blend, select Project | Build Project from the menu (or CTRL+SHIFT+B).